# Output files that are less than X old

Tags: php, time, filemtime

I am basically trying to only return files less than 1 day. The posts on here contain deleting files older than X days. I wish to return files that are less than 1 day. I figured it would be as simple as adding filemtime but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
function dirList ($directory){
   $results = array();
    $handler = opendir($directory);

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
            $results[] = $file;
    }
    closedir($handler);
    return $results; }
```

I have tried playing with filemtime and adding it to:

```
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && filemtime($file) < time() - 86400)
            $results[] = $file;
```

This just displays everything still.

```
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && filemtime($file) > time() - 86400)
            $results[] = $file;
```

Displays nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file` is a filename relative to `$directory`, but `filemtime` will interpret it relative to the process's current directory. You need to give correct pathname to `filenmtime`:

```
filemtime($directory . '/' . $file)
```

Comment: Ah i see, i presumed that because i was opening the $directory that filemtime would be executed within that directory. Much appreciated.